# IIS website not accessible remotely even after enabling firewall

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, iis-8.5

I have set up a website on port 80 in IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012. I am able to browse to the site locally, but can't access it remotely.

A common fix suggested for this problem was to check if the firewall allows inbound requests, so I set up an inbound rule in the firewall to accept requests to port 80.

Even after that, the website is inaccessible remotely.

Not sure what the problem is. Please help.

PS1: This is an IP address, I don't have a site name.
PS2: When I browse to the IP address locally on the server, I still can't access it.

Comment: Are you getting any specific error?

Comment: It tries to load the site for a minute or so and then, on the Chrome browser, I see the message "This site cannot be reached". It is basically a connection timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the router port 80 open and forwarding to the iis server IP?
Port scan test: https://mxtoolbox.com/portscan.aspx

Also you say you can access it locally and then later say that you can't -- please clairify???

Comment: When I say I can access it locally, I mean I can browse to the website with 'localhost' in the URL, like so: http://localhost/default.html, but when I replace 'localhost' with the IP address of the server (locally on the server), I can't browse to the website.

Comment: Paul, when I ran the port scan test, it showed a red 'X' mark against port 80. What do I need to do to enable it?

Comment: Open port 80 on your router and forward the port to the iis server.

Answer (score 0):

Few checks that you can do.

- Open command prompt on a client machine and run a ping on the IP address of the server. If ping is successful, go to the next step. If ping fails, then go to the server and run "ipconfig" on the command prompt to understand the IP address attached to your server.
- Run portqryUI tool from a client machine to check if port 80 is opened. You can download it from here - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24009
- If portqry indicates that port 80 is filtered or blocked, then run the following on the command prompt on the server

**netstat -ano >a.txt**

once you hit enter, the results will be saved in a file called "a.txt". To open it, simply type its name in the next line.

**a.txt**

Search for port "80" in this file and see if its being used by any other third party process.

Let me know what you find or if you are stuck anywhere !